# Figuring out the package name of a *.SWC file so that I can import it

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex3, swc, flash-builder4.5

I am a noob to flex so this probably comes across as a ridiculous error to you guys, but I can't for the life of me figure out what would be the name of the package/class for the .swc file I just added.

I am doing the typical steps, going into properties, flex builder path, Libraries tab and then adding the SWC. It shows up in my referenced libraries folder in my projects' package explorer. However, when I attempt to 'import', there are no drop down hints that suggest the name of the packet nor am I able to figure out the name of the package so that I could just bang it in.

For the record, I am installing FlexSpy, for those who are aware of this.

Best,
Parijat

Comment: You should be able to see the content of the swc in the package explorer. If not, your FlashBuilder is probably broken.

Comment: Usually, I would expect a SWC to come with instructions of some sort about the classes that come with it and how to use them.

Comment: @RIAstar your answer is correct. how do I acknowledge it since it's comment

Comment: Just made it a formal answer. I just didn't think this was the answer to your question at first.

Comment: @Flextras if you buy a single `.swc` library - yes. If you're in a corp. env. with tens of `.swc`s and no docs for them - no ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to see the content of the swc in the package explorer. Just double-click the library icon and it will expand into a package structure with classes. You can even inspect the class' properties and methods. If this doesn't work, your FlashBuilder is probably broken.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the `.swc` file to `.zip`

Open it using whatever you usually use for zip archives (Winzip, Winrar, "unzip -l", ...)

The `catalog.xml` file in root dir will contain the packages names.